# Exchange partition with materialized view in oracle

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I created a materialized view on a table.

SRC_TBL  --->  MV

Trying to do exchange partition between materialized view and target table.

MV ---> TGT_TBL

It throws me ORA-14097 error message although all the columns between materialized view and target table are of same type.

Appreciate your inputs.

Regards,
Dex.

Comment: Are there any unused columns? If so, they might be causing problems.

Comment: ALL_UNUSED_COL_TABS returned me no such columns

Comment: If you query ALL_CONSTRAINTS, is there any of them whose VALIDATED column value isn't "VALIDATED" (but "NOT VALIDATED")?

Comment: Tgt table has no constraints... materialized view has 3 constraints but the validated column is Validated only

Comment: Did you check all NOT NULL constraints too? Perhaps some of them are missing?

Comment: I dropped all constraints from materialized view and the table but it's still throwing same error

Comment: Oh, come on! It would be nice if you answered positively to at least one suggestion! (Just kidding :)). Can you afford dropping both MV and TGT_TBL and creating them from scratch? I'm afraid I'm out of new ideas ...

Comment: Do you have any virtual columns?

Comment: I was going to say hidden columns. Can't remember if MV creates them. Check DBA_TAB_COLS I think it shows them all.

Comment: @bobby durrett I dropped and recreated MV but it still gives same errror, check all unused tab

Comment: Maybe you should start by showing us the DDL for the table and the DDL for the mview.  Then show us the output from DBA_TAB_COLS for each.

Comment: Partition exchange can be tricky. There is something I am sure. Are the columns the same in terms of not null constraints? Takes me a few tries every time I do this.

Comment: I dropped the table multiple times and tried but it didn't work. I created a new table with different name and created partitions on that and then exchange partition worked, not sure why.